# Where is the signtool.exe located in windows 10 SDK?

Tags: signtool

I'm searching for the latest version of sign tool. Already installed latest windows 10 SDK, but signtool.exe date did not change.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Starting from windows 10 SDK, the signtool.exe is now located here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64`

In this example, I used the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK-Version (10.0.16299) - and 64bit edition

Be careful, additionally it may be located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit`

Update: Windows 10 Build 1809, now here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64`

Update: Visual Studio 2022: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64`

Comment: And now... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64`

Comment: this is sick they keep changing location

Comment: The signtool can be located by navigating to the directory `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin` and searching for `signtool`. Then look for the result where location ends with `[...]\{higest version number}\x64`.

Comment: I'm not saying that all software stuff from Microsoft is messy... but this particular one is just... wow! I'm working on a CI for the first time and I want a clean solution to sign files automatically, and I don't know what's the best way now...

Comment: Great place to hide it on a 64 bit PC

Answer (score 16):

If I do not install Windows 10 SDK, but install Visual Studio, I typically find signtool.exe in the following location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe`

This is a constant path that doesn't depend on the version of the Windows SDK. It's very convenient to use it in bat files or another automation stuff.

Comment: Be aware that this is a much older version of SignTool.exe, that doesn't support exactly the same options as the newer ones, and as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Answer (score 0):

If you install the 'Windows 10 SDK' ( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/ ) then it'll be at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` as somewhere static that won't change.

Comment: I can't find a signtool.exe there

Answer (score 0):

You could find:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe"
```